# Using emoji in xaringan presentation

Tags: r, r-markdown, xaringan

I'd like to know if there is a way to use markdown syntax for adding emoji in `xaringan` presentation. A minimal example would be

```
---

# Slide #1 :smile:

---
```

that would produce

## Slide #1

Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you knit that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since xaringan is an html5 page, you can insert an emoji in it like any other webpage. Multiple ways to do so:

1. Insert emoji directly: copy & paste the emoji  into the rmd, knit your slides and it'll work.
2. Insert unicode emoji using HTML character escape:

   - [From this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miscellaneous_Symbols) you can lookup an emoticon and copy & paste the html code`&#9728;` into your rmd file, which will be rendered as ☀ . The `&#` and `;` are used to escape the unicode character.
3. There's a [package](https://github.com/hadley/emo) `emo` by Hadley, which is designed  to make it very easy to insert emoji into RMarkdown documents." so you can do

   ```
   ---

   # Slide #1 `r emo::ji("smile")`

   ---
   ```

Comment: I tried all your solutions but faced a major problem : I can not see emojis inside Rstudio (Source, Console and Viewer), in all cases (`inf_mr`, knitting, ...). Howerver, I can see them in the html file opened externaly (web browser). I guess this is only the case for Windows OS, could you  confirm it, or at least precise your OS ? Thanks in advance

Comment: I think it's related to the web browser.

Comment: Thanks for this, I used the emo package, but the emoji is really small. Any suggestions about how to make it much larger?